# jQuery - Don't allow click event with parent has something children element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html code like this:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li class="prev"><span>&#8592;</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="next"><a href="javascript::void(0)">&#8594;</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div><!-- .pagination -->
```

When I add click event for li tag, I want to click **li** tag **don't have span** children element.It means that if I **click** on **it**, **do nothing** but **other** I can click and **do something**. How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried any code over on jsfiddle.net? Might help us out.

Comment: Why not just bind a click event to the anchors?

Comment: #dmayo I never try it but sure, I'll try. #Phil I have a mistake. I wrote a long code click event with li tag but I'll rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the `:not()` and `:has()` pseudo selectors to do that :

```
$('.pagination ul li:not(:has(span))').on('click', function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yBxgy/)

It does seem easier to just do :

```
$('.pagination ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: But if I using this code $('.pagination ul li a'), how do it work?